# How to fix object representaions in django admin page on `LogEntry` model. django 2.2

Tags: python, django

I've added a code in my view to log every add action in my `add_new_staff` page. However, everytime I add a user on that page, the columns `object_id` and `object_repr` in `LogEntry` model in admin page gets this weird data representations(objects encircled with black pen):

[image]

The objects encircled with red pen are the users I added on the django admin page, and it didn't get weird representations.

These are the code I added in my `add_staff_view` :

```
@login_required
def StaffSignUpView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = accounts_forms.StaffSignUpForm(request.POST)
        profileform = accounts_forms.UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and profileform.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            userprofile = profileform.save(commit=False)
            userprofile.user = user
            userprofile.save()
            first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
            last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
            message = f'New user added. Added staff profile for {user.first_name} {user.last_name}.'

            log = LogEntry.objects.log_action(
                user_id=request.User.id,
                content_type_id=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(User).pk,
                object_id=str(User.id),
                # or any field you wish to represent here
                object_repr=str(User.username),
                action_flag=ADDITION,  # assuming it's a new object
                change_message=message,)  # a new user has been added

            log.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Account created for {0} {1}!'.format(
                first_name, last_name))
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = accounts_forms.StaffSignUpForm()
        profileform = accounts_forms.UserProfileForm()

    context = {
        'profileform': profileform,
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'accounts/registration/register.html', context)
```

How can I fix this problem? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You should show the rest of the view. `User` is the model, not the instance; if the instance is `user` for example, you should use `user.pk` and `user.username`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman oh, I'm sorry, I updated the question for you.

Comment: Thank you @DanielRoseman, i tried to replace `User` by `user` and it works fine now!